Handle disconnection with Flutter Clean Architecture
Sometimes the users of my mobile app may be disconnected for some reason, like when their token expires for example. How to handle these disconnection properly without having to put try catch on every remote data source methods of my app ? Or doing so but by not having to verbosely and repeatedly make the error go up until presentation layer to handle it ?
It works by making the error go up across all layers but I think that's not very clean to write repetitive and verbose code.

You can use centralized error handling like using an interceptor or something like wrapping an API call in some global method which handles your error.
